# How to remove a UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4

I have a nib with four UIViewControllers each with a UITabBarItem.  At runtime, based on user options, I need to show or hide one of the UITabBarItems.  I cannot figure out how to remove the UITabBatItem.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christian's code is close. It should be:

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:myTabBarController.viewControllers];
[viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:indexToRemove];
[myTabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

Comment: Ahh yes, duh, ok I am new to all this and there's a alot to go through!!  Thanks for the help, I should have known that.

Answer (score 1):

To remove one, you can just get the viewControllers from the TabBar and put them in an NSMutableArray. Then remove the index you want removed and then set the viewControllers property to this new array of view controllers using

```
setViewControllers:animated:
```

Hoep this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Get the tab bar controller's view controllers, remove the one you want to 'hide' and then set the tab bar controller's viewControllers array to this new array.

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [myTabBarController viewControllers];
[viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:indexToRemove];
[myTabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
```

Comment: Yes, I tried something similar earlier but I get 'Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray *' with an expression of type 'NSArray *'